# Spring IDE plugin vs STS: feature comparison for version 3.3.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Does anyone know where I can find the most recent feature comparison document for Spring IDE plugin vs SpringSource Tool Suite STS (version 3.3.0)?

I believe Eclipse made some good progress in Kepler release, (for example Maven support being shipped in) so was wondering if the feature gap between Eclipse+Spring IDE plugin and STS highlighted in [2.9.2 Feature Comparison](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/doc/STS-feature_comparison.pdf) were reduced in Eclipse Java EE Kepler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is not much difference now between Eclipse + Spring-IDE and STS.  The main difference is that when you download STS, you are guaranteed that all the bits and pieces work together.  When you install Eclipse + Spring-IDE, you may have some compatibility problems and trouble installing or upgrading.

My advice is this: if you already have an Eclipse that has custom plugins installed, then go with Eclipse + Spring-IDE and if you are starting from scratch, go with STS.

Comment: I did the feature comparison myself and realised the two are virtually similar except for some minor differences such as the vFabric tc Server Developer Edition being shipped-in with STS but requiring additional plugin in Eclipse